# Why is a test (100/100) leading to an unexpected output?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am trying to learn python. In this context, I work on this exercise:

- I take a fraction from the user (X/Y) and return a result
- If Y is greater than X, I prompt the user to provide another fraction
- If X or X are not integers, I prompt the user to provide another fraction
- If X is greater than Y, I prompt the user to provide another fraction
- If the fraction leads to a result over 99%, I print F
- If the fraction leads to a result below 1%, I print E

My code is as follows:

```
z = input("Fraction: ")
k = z.split("/")

while True:
    try:
        x = int(k[0])
        y = int(k[1])
        if y >= x:
           result = round((x / y) * 100)
        else:
           z = input("Fraction: ")
# if x and y are integer and y greater or equal to x, then divide, and round x and y

    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        z = input("Fraction: ")

# if x and y are not integer or y is zero, prompt the user again

    else:
        break

# exit the loop if the condition is met and print (either F, E or the result of the division)

if result >= 99:
    print("F")
elif 0 <= result <= 1:
    print("E")
else:
    print(f"{result}%")
```

The input of `100/100` leads to another prompt, when it should lead to `F` as an output.

I do not understand why.

Comment: Can't reproduce. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I tried to insure that this could be reproducible by providing the code, the input and output. I do not understand how the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I input `100/100` and get `F` as result.

Comment: I do not on my side. But let me know this is not meeting the point defined in [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.10.11. I pass all the defined "test" except this one. This is a mystery to me.

Comment: It's not reproducible because it involves you or us potentially inputting different things.

Comment: OK! Many thanks for this pointer! I inputted exactly "100/100" as communicated in the question.

Comment: Then replace your sample code with `z = "100/100"`?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Let me put it bluntly: you say you input `100/100`. I don't trust you. To remove that suspicion, show me that you still get your error if you define `z = "100/100"` in your code rather than using user input.

Comment: Tried with `100/100` as user input, and result if `F`, not another prompt. Also, you mention "If Y is greater than X, I prompt the user to provide another fraction" - I don't think that is what you want here.

Comment: You mean that it should be if Y is greater or equal than X @KrishnadevN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so the problem stems from your placement of the K variable. While you are assigning input to K initially, if for whatever reason the first input were to throw the zero division error or a value error, the program doesn't work as expected because you never reevaluate the input hence just moving your k variable into your try clause, or more accurately into the while loop, should fix the issue:

```
z = input("Fraction: ")
while True:
    try:
        k = z.split("/")
        x = int(k[0])
        y = int(k[1])
        if y >= x:
           result = round((x / y) * 100)
        else:
           z = input("Fraction: ")
           continue
# if x and y are integer and y greater or equal to x, then divide, and round x and y

    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        z = input("Fraction: ")

# if x and y are not integer or y is zero, prompt the user again

    else:
        break

# exit the loop if the condition is met and print (either F, E or the result of the division)

if result >= 99:
    print("F")
elif 0 <= result <= 1:
    print("E")
else:
    print(f"{result}%")
```

As an added note, be more clear in your initial question and ensure you provide all of the inputs you have made, the best way to ensure you provide us with all of your inputs, rerun your program and make note of  any inputs then on including blank inputs in problems like this.

Edit: Added a continue in the case that the y < x which would result in another input being required hence the result wouldn't be defined.

Comment: @Elvino Michel you understand now why creating a [mre] is crucial?

Comment: Many thanks @TheCyberFox! Yes this was the issue!

Comment: What do you mean by *rerun your program and make note of any inputs then on including blank inputs in problems like this.* @TheCyberFox ?

Comment: Yes @Julien I am sorry. I really tried my best to produce and extensive example. I am sorry for the frustration. I felt I had met the guideline, and provided the code, along with the wrong output. I did not intended to cause frustration, and I wished to provide a well researched question.

Comment: If you wish to make a question here, place yourself in our shoes when you ask the question i.e. run the script and from the default run state i.e. from when it is first ran i.e. no inputs have been provided yet, take note of all of the inputs you provide and ensure you provide said inputs in your question. In your question you only provided "100/100" But you more than likely had pressed enter a few times or provided "some number/0" before hand.

Comment: @ElvinoMichel no worries, just remember for next time. As previous comments, a MRE should not use uncontrolled `input()`, and should be run from scratch. BTW if you had done that while writing the question, you'd most likely have found the issue by yourself. This is part of good debugging skills.